# I don't know why this list in Python behaving like this

Tags: python, list

Firstly I am a beginner in python and this is where I got struck

Here class card returns a string

When I print the list itself without giving an index it shows me a garbage value, but when I give an index it shows me the value that I want. I don't know why this is happening.

```
class Card:

    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit=suit
        self.rank=rank


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.rank} of {self.suit}'


allcards=[]
allcards.append(Card('Spades','Jack'))

print(allcards)
```

Output: `[<__main__.Card object at 0x0000013B5E72EFD0>]`

```
class Card:

    def __init__(self,suit,rank):
        self.suit=suit
        self.rank=rank


    def __str__(self):
        return f'{self.rank} of {self.suit}'

allcards=[]
allcards.append(Card('Spades','Jack'))

print(allcards[0])
```

Output: `Jack of Spades`

**I want to print the list by using the first case how can I?**

Comment: Because when you print a list it prints the `__repr__`s of its contents, not their `__str__`s.

Comment: Use `print(*allcards)`

Comment: Thanks for your valuable suggestions.

Comment: its not working here vscode says **Unpack operation not allowed in this context** @Barmar
`print(f'{player_one.name} cards : {*player_one.allcards}')`

Comment: Ok I got it to avoid this use `def __repr__ ()`instead of `def __str__()` when returning a string in a class to print list without giving an index

Comment: @VamshiKrishnaReddy That's not what I said to do. I said `print(*allcards)` instead of `print(allcards)`

Comment: @Barmar yes, I agree but implementing my code using the same principle doesn't work, here I posted the code which is a shorter version of my code but the problem is the same. Playerone is an  instance of the Player class in that I initialized allcards list, modified it using some other functions  so i need to print allcards using player one instance ie `playerone.allcards` it's showing me the first case output but I need to find out the way to get the second case  output

Comment: without replacing `__repr__` with `__str__` is there any way to do it?

Comment: You could create a `Deck` class and define its `__str__` method, instead of using an ordinary list. Or you could define a `printCards()` function that prints a list of cards the way you want.